# Wrong colors on shaded triangle

Tags: c, colors, geometry, sdl, gfx

I was trying to draw a shaded triangle, but I get wrong colors. Here's the example of what I get, if I call a function with red, green and blue colors:

[image]

It should be red on the top left, green on the top right and blue on the top bottom. But as you can see the colors are not like that. I should get something like this:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
unsigned RGB(unsigned char R, unsigned char G, unsigned B){
    return  (R << 16) | (G << 8) | B;
}

    float get_dist(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2){
            int xproj = x2-x1;
            int yproj = y2-y1;
            float dist = sqrt(pow(xproj, 2) + pow(yproj, 2));
            return dist;
    }
    unsigned char getR(unsigned c){
            return (c >> 16) & 0xFF;
    }
    unsigned char getG(unsigned c){
            return (c >> 8) & 0xFF;
    }
    unsigned char getB(unsigned c){
            return c & 0xFF;
    }
    void draw_ftriangle(SDL_Surface * s, int x0, int y0, unsigned c0, int x1, int y1, unsigned c1, int x2, int y2, unsigned c2){
            int x;
            signed d0, d1, d2;
            unsigned R, G, B, color;
            int ymin = min(y0, min(y1, y2));
            int xmin = min(x0, min(x1, x2));
            int ymax = max(y0, max(y1, y2));
            int xmax = max(x0, max(x1, x2));
            draw_line(s, x0, y0, x1, y1, color);
            draw_line(s, x1, y1, x2, y2, color);
            draw_line(s, x0, y0, x2, y2, color);
            for(; ymin < ymax; ymin++)
                    for(x=xmin; x < xmax; x++)
                            if(ptintr(x, ymin, x0, y0, x1, y1, x2, y2)){
                                    d0 = get_dist(x, ymin, x0, y0);
                                    d1 = get_dist(x, ymin, x1, y1);
                                    d2 = get_dist(x, ymin, x2, y2);
                                    R = d0+d1+d2 == 1 ? getR(c0)*d0 + getR(c1)*d1 + getR(c2)*d2 :
                                                                             (getR(c0)*d0 + getR(c1)*d1 + getR(c2)*d2)/(d0+d1+d2);
                                    G = d0+d1+d2 == 1 ? getG(c0)*d0 + getG(c1)*d1 + getG(c2)*d2 :
                                                                            (getG(c0)*d0 + getG(c1)*d1 + getG(c2)*d2)/(d0+d1+d2);
                                    B = d0+d1+d2 == 1 ? getB(c0)*d0 + getB(c1)*d1 + getB(c2)*d2 :
                                                                            (getB(c0)*d0 + getB(c1)*d1 + getB(c2)*d2)/(d0+d1+d2);
                                    color = RGB(R, G, B);
                                    put_pixel(s, x, ymin, color);
                            }
    }
```

I call a function drraw_ftriangle like that:

draw_ftriangle(surface, 100, 100, RGB(255, 0, 0),
                        235, 150, RGB(0, 255, 0),
                        4, 254, RGB(0, 0, 255));

I'm not sure, but I think the problem should be here:

```
R = (d0+d1+d2) == 1 ? getR(c0)*d0 + getR(c1)*d1 + getR(c2)*d2 :
                      (getR(c0)*d0 + getR(c1)*d1 + getR(c2)*d2)/(d0+d1+d2);
```

Same with G and B variables...

I'd like other people to explain me, where's the problem, because I'm searching for it all day long...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `R` and `G` parameters to your `RGB` function are `unsigned char`, and you are not casting them to `unsigned int` before shifting.  That means, you're shifting an 8-bit number.  You know what happens...

So, either convert the parameters to `unsigned int` or cast the values before shifting.

PS: Whatever you do, it would be nice if you made all three parameters the same type!

As in comments, turns out it was this:

> So I don't think your (x,y) coordinates are normalised in that
>   get_dist function. You compute the length of the hypoteneuse
>   connecting those two vectors, but you don't give it any base lengths
>   to normalise on.

Comment: Hmm, on second thoughts, I seem to be reading about `char` being implicitly converted to `int` on shift.  In that case, my answer is not appropriate.  If anybody can verify that I am wrong, please let me know and I will remove this answer.

Comment: I've changed RGB arguments to unsigned int, but I still got the same colors.

Comment: That'd be good practice at least...  So I don't think your `(x,y)` coordinates are normalised in that `get_dist` function.  You compute the length of the hypoteneuse connecting those two vectors, but you don't give it any base lengths to normalise on.  Am I missing something else here?

Comment: Thanks! I've changed d0 = get_dist(x, ymin, x0, y0); to d0 = 1/(get_dist(x, ymin, x0, y0)); (same with d1 and d2) and it worked fine! Thanks again.